# Using C# Attributes, how would I trigger functions to be executed on change of their assigned field

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

I am currently developing a network Library for Unity as the one integrated is not quite what our game needs.
Several things such as too much abstraction and many limitations forced us come up with our own solution.

The whole communication happens on top of standard .Net Sockets.
The system we developed is mostly built using internal classes and structures that don't really need to be explained any further.

The important thing is our `ShatNetTransportLayer` class.
It's a static class that internally uses two buffers, one for the receiving of data, one for the transmitting.
Another higher level class works pretty much like a "network gc".
Messages get pushed onto a send list, which is regularly being checked and freed, once all messages have been send. This is of course simplified, actually there are ack checks for different channels etc.

So far to the setup.
The important thing I need to know is as follows.

Each Object in the game that is to be networked will hold a `ShatNetIdentity`.
This is the core class that registers networked objects on the server and keeps them sycned on each client side.
While this isn't fully implemented yet, we have another problem to overcome.
The plan is that each `ShatNetIdentity`will be the core component of a networked gameobject, so that any `ShatNetBehaviour` can access it via the gameobject.

`ShatNetBehaviour` is a class derived from monobehaviour which is Unity's default class to deal with in scene elements.
The only thing it adds on top of it is the possibility to get the `ShatNetIdentity` associated with the object the script is attached to.

Now comes the *crucial* part:

Since we have devs in our team that never barely touched a networking system, we **need** to **abstract** the syncing of variables, probably even the remote method calls.

Internally all that will be sent is the message with a max size of 128Byte.
Part of that is the MessageType, a 1Byte long unsigned int that represents the type of the message, like Variable syncs, message calls, disconnected players and that stuff.
Second is the sender ID represented by 2Byte. 
Rest is the message itself. 
There is more involved but that's the core.
This is still to be fully determined, but you get the idea. 
These messages are written to the buffer and send when a send is scheduled or received when receive event occured.

Back when we used Unity's own UNet, you could just add an attribute called `SyncVar` to any field of a class which is part of an object that has a `ShatNetIdentity` attached.
There was also a way to define a callback function if the value changed.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html

Example:

```
//When this is not our client, this value will be updated automatically across the net
[SyncVar(hook="OnHealthChanged")]
int health;


void OnHealthChanged()
{
doStuff();
}
```

So my question is, is there any way to implement this ourselves?

The names we had in mind are NetVar and NetHook.
To have a variable synced accross the network one would simply write

```
[NetVar]
private int health;

void TakeDamage(int amount)
{
//Updates health for all clients
   health-=amount;
}
```

To make this happen, several things would happen.

1. When a new ShatNetIdentity is spawned, register it on the server.
2. Register every variable of each class that is attached to a gameobject with 
   ShatNetIdentity on that identity.
   Probably not possible that way, because access levels? Use public properties inside of the attribute ?
3. When receive buffer is populated check messages for variable update types, find the index of the ShatNetIdentity and the referenced variable.
4. Update that variable on each client

So things I'd need to get a hint for would be

1. how do I reference private variables on a ShatNetIdentity(Could be any class of course). Supported types are base types, nothing else, but there must be one attribute that covers them all. Nothing like NetBool, NetInt...
2. How do I reference callback functions with an attribute and trigger them when the value of the field is changed.
3. What other options could I use.

Ideas that I had so far:
Create networked basetypes for every base type.
This would look ugly and wouldn't really help maintining easy code.

I hope I explained everything well enough. If any detail needed, just shoot.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit:
Looks like SynVar is just a tag for code to be generated.

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/29/unet-syncvar

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, for your case, you could go one of two routes. A broadcast style system, or a registration style system.

In a **Broadcast** scenario, your communications component (class), could declare something like:

```
public event Action<(string shatNetIdentity, MessageType messageType, string message)> Message;
```

And then invoke when a message is correctly received:

```
Message?.Invoke((id, messageType, message));
```

The receiving object would then have to determine if the message was intended for it, and if so, what type of message it actually was and how to deal with it.

In a **Register** scenario, your objects could register to the communications component. You could have a Dictionary in your comms component:

```
private Dicitionary<string, INetworkObject> Registrations;

public void Register(INetworkObject o)
{
  Registrations[o.ShatNetIdentity] = o;
}

private void ReceiveMessage()
{
  // receive and parse message.
  if ( Registrations.TryGet(message.Id, out INetworkObject o )
  {
    switch (message.messageType)
    {
      case MessageType.Health: 
      o.Health = message.Health;
      break;
      // etc..
    }
  }
}
```

Where INetworkObject is something like:

```
public interface INetworkObject
{
  string ShatNetIdentity {get; set;}
  float Health { get; set; }
  Vector3 Position {get; set;}
}
```

There's obviously no error checking here. And if it were me, I'd probably go with the second scenario. The first scenario might be easier to implement if there were only a few objects listening to the event, but isn't optimal if there are many objects, as the event is broadcast to every object listening.

Comment: I actually like the idea of the registration system.

Comment: This isn't the answer 1:1 But I am marking it as the accepted answer since this totally helped me implement the given scenario in a very similar way and thus this will help anyone with the same problem. Thank you a lot dude!